# Casimir force without cheating

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

If memory serves me right, some years ago I heard rumors about developing methods 
of computing the Casimir force which are rigorous  (by the standards of constructive quantum field theory).   I become interested in this subject more recently, but it seems there is no way to find it in the flood created by physicists.  (I really did not find a single paper.)
Does anyone know relevant references?

[EDIT]  Now that I think about it, this question may be  misunderstood. What I mean are, of course, methods of calculating the Casimir force  in  nontrivial cases. (Such as  complex geometry  or  two parallel but inhomogeneous plates.)    There is a vast physical literature about this.

Answer (score 1):

[Casimir Energy of a Ball and Cylinder in the Zeta Function Technique](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9812059), 1998.

> With this technique one succeeds, specifically, in justifying, in
>   mathematically rigorous way, the appearance of the contribution to the
>   Casimir energy for perfectly conducting spherical and cylindrical
>   shells.

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting work I did not know about. However, it may be not what I meant. While published in Journal of Mathematical Physics, this seems to me a work on the physical level of rigor.  There seems to be no proof, in the paper or in references, that the method they use produces a correct result. (Even if there is little doubt that it does.)